# position:fixed перекрывает собой все нижеследующие блоки

Tags: css3

Вопрос такой - почему при использовании position:fixed он как бы "уводит" под себя нижеследующие блоки?

Пример того, что у меня получилось: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jzjawxuo/)

И как можно это исправить? Кроме как сделать пустой блок, равный по высоте шапке, пока ни до чего не дошел.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так и должно быть - ведь position:fixed может использоваться не только для шапки. В вашем случае, и правда, лучше всего будет расположить под шапкой пустой блок такого же размера.